# Modify LaTeX table p-values by multiple conditions

Tags: pdftex

I have LaTeX tables being automatically generated (populated) via R (Brew, Knitr), and compiled with PdfLaTeX (MiKTeX). There are rows of p-values for each statistic test. I would like to have LaTeX automatically format them for two conditions:

1. if the p-value <= 0.05 and >= 0.01, then bold the value with a trailing asterisk;
2. if the p-value < 0.01, then insert a `<` sign in front of a new bolded value = 0.01.

If a p-value does not satisfy any of those conditions (i.e., > 0.05), then keep that original p-value. Below is an example LaTeX table, followed by an example expected table.

```latex
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption*{\textbf{Table}: Statistics for A, B, C.}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Statistic & A     & B       & C        \\
Mean      & 8.3   & 9.4     & 7.6      \\
t         & 0.82  & 0.72    & 0.92     \\
p-value   & 0.06  & 0.12    & 0.05     \\
wmw       & 80.23 & 1000.34 & 1243.44  \\
p-value   & 0.04  & 0.09    & 0.00    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

```latex
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption*{\textbf{Table}: Statistics for A, B, C.}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Statistic & A             & B       & C                         \\
Mean      & 8.3           & 9.4     & 7.6                       \\
t         & 0.82          & 0.72    & 0.92                      \\
p-value   & 0.06          & 0.12    & \textbf{0.05}             \\
wmw       & 80.23         & 1000.34 & 1243.44                   \\
p-value   & \textbf{0.04} & 0.09    & \textless{}\textbf{0.01} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I've tried `\ifnum` many times with no success, returning the error `! Missing number, treated as zero.`

```latex
\newcommand\pval[1]{
    \ifnum{#1}<{0.05}=0
        \textbf{#1}
    else
        #1
    fi
}
```

Comment: Why not left the conditional part in R:  `if (x$p.value > 0.05) { .... } else {....}` al left to  LaTeX just print the result?

Comment: Letting R do the conditions isn't possible. R has each value in a data frame, for named columns. The data frames are then injected into a Sweave document via Brew, and converted to latex and compiled via Knitr. I believe the conditions will need to be evaluated on compile.

Comment: Keep in mind that it R who makes the table, at once it is done, it is done. Without a concrete example is hard to say but what prevents you of modify the column or row of the data frame automatically and then go as usual? This seems to me a lot more feasible the modify an already made  normal LaTeX table evaluating the content of some cells (i.e, I think that is not possible in this way).

Comment: R does not make the table. The table is already made and contained within a Sweave template. R only holds the data inside of data frames. Brew then finds strings in the template corresponding to the data frame and column name, and replaces the string with the data value. So, unless one can add both the latex format with embedded data value into a data frame, then what you’re proposing cannot be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `\ifnum` with integers. With floats you need to use something like `\FPiflt` from the [fp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp) package. You can also "automate" this using a combination of the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package, to define a new column type, and the [collcell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell) package, to pass the contents of the cell to a macro. The two crucial lines below are:

```
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\pval}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand\pval[1]{\FPiflt{#1}{0.5}\textbf{#1}\else#1\fi}
```

These lines define a line `P` column type that applies the `\pcal` macro to each cell. With this in place your the MWE in the OP produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{fp,collcell,array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\pval}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand\pval[1]{\FPiflt{#1}{0.5}\textbf{#1}\else#1\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption*{\textbf{Table}: Statistics for A, B, C.}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{lllP}
Statistic & A     & B       &\multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
Mean      & 8.3   & 9.4     & 7.6      \\
t         & 0.82  & 0.72    & 0.92     \\
p-value   & 0.06  & 0.12    & 0.05     \\
wmw       & 80.23 & 1000.34 & 1243.44  \\
p-value   & 0.04  & 0.09    & 0.00
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need to use `\multicolumn` for the column header. I have just put the entry if bold if it is less than 0.5 The other decorations can be added in the same way.

**EDIT**

If, as stated in the comments, you don't want to apply this special formatting to the entire column then you can just manually add `\pval` to the table entries as required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand\pval[1]{\FPiflt{#1}{0.5}\textbf{#1}\else#1\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption*{\textbf{Table}: Statistics for A, B, C.}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Statistic & A     & B       &C       \\
Mean      & 8.3   & 9.4     & 7.6      \\
t         & 0.82  & 0.72    & 0.92     \\
p-value   & 0.06  & 0.12    & \pval{0.05}\\
wmw       & 80.23 & 1000.34 & 1243.44  \\
p-value   & 0.04  & 0.09    & 0.00
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’d like to avoid collcell and array as much as I can. Those two packages are far too hard-coded to allow for the flexibility the table needs (i.e., any number smaller than 0.05 in any P-column could be modified). This begs format failures for random data combinations. The table I included is just made-up data, and the mean for a column could be smaller than 0.05. Could I rather just use the pval newcommand and evaluate each p-value: \pval{0.04} would be compiled as \textbf{0.04}^{*}?

Comment: I assumed that you want to apply this formatting to the entire column. If it is just the occasional entry then of course you can just put `\pval{0.04}` into the table (and use a a standard column type). See my edit.