# Create and Fill table using a function in latex with colors and conditions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have the below table in my presentation and I need to create a function which takes a parameters for example

```
% developer: Boolean if true we will have colored circle in developer row (default true)
% devOps   : Boolean if true we will have colored circle in devOps row (default true)
% business : Boolean if true we will have colored circle in business row (default true)
% watchMethod: Int if 1 we will add all the circle under Computer column, if 2 Mobile/Tablet column else Just listening column (default listening if not passed as argument)
% length   : it is an indecator for colors if 1 red, 2 blue, else green (default green if not passed as an argument)
def makeTargetLectureClassificationTable(developer:Boolean, devOps:Boolean, business:Boolean, watchingMethod:Int, length:Int)={
}
```

Sample of the table code is below

```
%circle inside table
\newcommand*\redcircled{\tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (.5ex);}
\newcommand*\bluecircled{\tikz\draw[blue,fill=blue] (0,0) circle (.5ex);}
\newcommand*\greencircled{\tikz\draw[green,fill=green] (0,0) circle (.5ex);}
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{|c |c | c | c|}
        \hline
        \thead{Watching Method \\ / Audience}  & \thead{Computer} & \thead{Mobile/Tablet} &  \thead{Just    listening} \\
        \hline
        \thead{Developer} &   &  \bluecircled & \\
        \hline
        \thead{DevOps}  &  & \bluecircled &  \\
        \hline
        \thead{Business} &  & \bluecircled & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The output screenshot below [image: here].

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511770/modify-latex-table-p-values-by-multiple-conditions?rq=1

Comment: http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432073/macro-not-working-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that I understand what you want but perhaps the code below will help. I have defined a macro `\VideoClassification` that creates your video classification table. This macro accepts key-value pairs for the different settings. I have used a slightly different syntax for develop etc as this was more straightforward to implementand I have used names that made more sense to me:

- By default markers are put into the three rows and you can "turn off" the marker using `nodev`, `nodevops` and `nobus`, respectively. By default all rows have markers
- The column that markers appear in is specified with `column=n`, where `n` is `1`, `2` or `3` (default `3`)
- The colour of the marker is given by `colour=<col>` where `col` can be any valid colour (not just `green`, `blue` and `red`). By default, the markers are `green`.

These comma separated keys can be given in any order.

Using this syntax the commands:

```
  \VideoClassification
  \VideoClassification[nodev, column=2]
  \VideoClassification[column=1, colour=red]
```

produce (with annoying amounts of extra space because of the table environment):

[image]

The basic idea is to use [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) to parse the arguments to the `\VideoClassification`. The keys set the colour and the column and then the markers are printed using the pgfkey `mark` that takes two arguments, which specify the column and row, respectively. There are more explanatory comments in the code below. I am sure that there are more efficient ways of doing this!

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/Videos/.is family, /Videos,
  bus/.initial=1,% by default the business row has a marker
  dev/.initial=1,% by default the developer row has a marker
  devops/.initial=1,% by default the developerOps row has a marker
  colour/.initial=green,% the colour of the marker
  column/.initial=3,% the column of the marker
  mark/.code 2 args={% place a marker ONLY if #1=column and \VIDEO{#2}=1
    \ifnum#1=\VIDEO{column}%
      \ifnum1=\VIDEO{#2}%
        \tikz\draw[\VIDEO{colour},fill=\VIDEO{colour}] (0,0) circle (.5ex);%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  },
  nobus/.style={bus=0},% turn off marker for business
  nodev/.style={dev=0},% turn off marker for developer
  nodevops/.style={devops=0},% turn off marker for devoperOps
}
% shortcut to access key values
\newcommand\VIDEO[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Videos/#1}}

% Usage: \VideoClassification[optional key values]
\newcommand\VideoClassification[1][]{%
  \begin{table}[t]
    \pgfkeys{/Videos, #1}% key changes local to group (and macro)
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \thead{Watching Method \\ / Audience}  & \thead{Computer} & \thead{Mobile/Tablet} &  \thead{Just listening} \\
        \hline
        \thead{Developer}& \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={1}{dev}}   & \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={2}{dev}}   & \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={3}{dev}} \\
        \hline
        \thead{DevOps}   & \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={1}{devops}}& \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={2}{devops}}& \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={3}{devops}} \\
        \hline
        \thead{Business} & \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={1}{bus}}   & \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={2}{bus}}   & \pgfkeys{/Videos/mark={3}{bus}} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}

\begin{document}

  \VideoClassification

  \VideoClassification[nodev, column=2]

  \VideoClassification[column=1, colour=red]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, you made my day (Y)

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud Glad it's useful! :)