# How to conditionally display in bold a R generated p-value with the symbol < (<0.001 or < 0.001)?

Tags: conditionals, bold, r

I have LaTeX tables being automatically generated (populated) via R (Rstudio, Knitr), and compiled with PdfLaTeX (MiKTeX). There are rows of p-values for each statistic test.

I am using this newcommand from the fp package ([Modify LaTeX table p-values by multiple conditions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511770/modify-latex-table-p-values-by-multiple-conditions))

```
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\pval}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand\pval[1]{\FPiflt{#1}{0.5}\textbf{#1}\else#1\fi}
```

to display the p-values in bold text if they are below 0.05.
The example below which is a mix of Latex and R works fine

```
\pval{\Sexpr{format.pval (round (crr_1 $ coef ["gender",]["p-value"], 2), digits = 3, eps = 0.001, nsmall = 3)}}
```

and produces **0.040**.

However, when the results of the format.pval R function gives the value <0.001, it does not work and produces the following message: FP error: Illegal character < found in float number !.

I have the same problem when I use the package Publish as displayed in the example below.

```
\pval{\Sexpr{publish (csc_1, print = F) [[2]] $ regressionTable $ p [[1]]}}
```

How can I circumvent this problem by using the \FPiflt function or by another way to produce bold p-value of <0.001 ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\pval}[1]{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {#1}
    % remove all special characters
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {[<>=]} {} \l_tmpa_tl
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {\l_tmpa_tl}
    \fp_compare:nTF {\l_tmpa_fp <= 0.5} {
        \group_begin: \bfseries \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl \group_end:
    } {
        \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pval{0.8}
\pval{<0.001}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below updates `\pval` to condition on the presence of `<` within the captured cell/argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,collcell}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\pval}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pval[1]{%
  \def\pval@{#1}% Store value
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}
  \patchcmd{\pval@}{<}{}
    {\ifnum\fpeval{\pval@ < 0.5}=1
      \expandafter\textbf
     \fi
    {<\pval@}}% <success> - < was present
    {\ifnum\fpeval{\pval@ < 0.5}=1
      \expandafter\textbf
     \fi
    {\pval@}}% <failure> - no < present
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | P | }
  0.4 \\
  0.6 \\
  0.1 \\
  0.01 \\
  0.001 \\
  <0.001
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```